# Can だ/だった be omitted before conjunctive が?

Tags: grammar, particle-が, counters

On the results of measuring the amount of plastic found in a sample of 31 fish:

> その結果、９匹の体の中から大きさ**が**５ｍｍ以下のプラスチック**が**平均で１．１個見つかりました。
>   The result (was that) from 9 fish the size was at least 5mm of plastic but on average they found 1.1mm.

I'm struggling with several aspects of the grammar in this sentence:

1) Is the first が in bold a subject marker and the second が the conjunctive particle? Is there a だった omitted before this が?

2) Is the counter word 個 somehow used as a substitute for repeating the unit mm?

If not, then I'm lost on how to parse this sentence.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both が in this sentence are subject markers.

Consider this "double-subject" sentence (cf. 象は鼻が長い / 私は彼が好きだ):

> そのプラスチックは大きさが5mm以下だ。
>   Those plastic (fragments) are 5 mm or smaller in size.

Form a relative clause from this (note that ～以下 works as a no-adjective):

> 大きさが5mm以下のプラスチック
>   the plastic (fragments) which are 5 mm or smaller in size

With this as the subject of the main sentence, you can say:

> 大きさが5mm以下のプラスチックが見つかりました。
>   The plastic (fragments) which were 5 mm or smaller in size were found.

個 is a generic counter for small and round objects. 個 is not a pronoun and it never replaces a unit of length, time, etc. So this 1.1個 refers to the number of plastic fragments per fish (cf. リンゴを2個買った). 平均で means "on average".

> 大きさが5mm以下のプラスチックが平均で1.1個見つかりました。
>   An average of 1.1 plastic fragments which were 5 mm or smaller in size were found.