# Why is に used instead of の? 「ハワイからおみやげにマカダミア•ナッツを買って来る」

Tags: grammar

> **(A)** ハワイからおみやげにマカダミア•ナッツを買って来る
>
> > I'll buy you guys a gift of macadamia nuts in Hawaii

> **(B)** ハワイからマカダミア•ナッツのおみやげを買って来る

I suppose に here indicates the purpose of the action like in the following:

> あなたはテレビゲームにお金を使いすぎます

If that's the case, would **B** sound unnatural because the noun modifier is too long?

From the same book, の is being used instead in another example, but the noun modifier is shorter:

> 田中さんのうちへ行く時、チーズのおみやげを持って行こう。

Comment: This に often translates as "**for**" or "**as**". 「お土産にもおすすめです」 _(We) recommend (this) for souvenirs._

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That に is a role/function marker like *as* in English. See the following questions:

- [に to indicate the role you want something to play?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/65432/5010)
- [grammar of 前の誕生日プレゼントにもらった彼女の絵](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/73351/5010)
- [Meaning of にと思って in a sentence](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/55453/5010)

マカダミアナッツのおみやげを買う is not wrong, but it's more natural to use おみやげに. の in ～のおみやげ is more commonly used as a possession marker rather than an apposition marker (e.g., 彼のお土産 is "his gift" or "gift for him"). If you want to use an [appositive の](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/40896/5010), おみやげのマカデミアナッツを買う sounds better (although it's still less common than おみやげに). I don't think the length of マカデミアナッツ matters here.