# Parsing 朝ごはんにりんごを食べます

Tags: grammar, particle-に

According to *A Dictionary of Intermediate Japanese Grammar*, under the には entry, には can take a noun if it's a [noun of action](https://japbase.neocities.org/intermediate/Intermediate%E3%81%AB%E3%81%AF.png) (third paragraph). には is に + は after all, so I assume that the same rule applies for just に (they're not that specific). If so, I don't see how 朝ごはん is noun of action. This is the only sentence that I've come across that doesn't follow this trend, yet it's said to be the purpose particle に in *The Japanese Stage-Step Course*.

[image]

Comment: Does The Japanese Stage-Step Course give more explanation or examples of what it calls "purpose に"?  If so can you edit your question to include that?  I think the books you have define that a little differently.

Comment: Maybe the book sees it as "I eat apples for [the purpose of doing] breakfast"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, that explanation ("に functions to express the purpose of *an action*") seems misleading to me. 朝ご飯 is a simple noun, and 朝ご飯する is ungrammatical. Here, this に is a rather simple role/purpose marker described in several previous questions. It roughly corresponds to "as" or "for" in English.

- [に to indicate the role you want something to play?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/65432/5010)
- [Meaning of にと思って in a sentence](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/55453/5010)
- [Can に have the same function as として?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/82913/5010)
- [grammar of 前の誕生日プレゼントにもらった彼女の絵](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/73351/5010)

に can also take a suru-verb as a purpose, for example 運転には免許が必要だ ("To drive it, you need a license"), but your sentence about 朝ご飯 is slightly different.

Comment: One of my books would classify this に as *The ocassion for an action*.

Comment: @Nameless I'm not familiar with that particular phrase...

Comment: Sorry for the late response. It means *The event in which some action takes place*.

Comment: @Nameless This type of に can take nouns that are clearly not events (e.g., 議長に彼を推薦する, テーマに桜を選ぶ, バットを武器に使用する). And に in 朝食にりんごを食べた is not a time/location marker (∼ "in/at") but a role/function marker (∼ "as/for"). I can say this because 朝食にテレビを見た is wrong but 朝食にリンゴを買う is correct.

Comment: Yes, this is why I prefer your explanation.